# JQuery - On list change show/hide element with ID matching option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains dynamically created tables.  The IDs of these tables, stored in a DB, can match the values of the select list on the page.

All of the tables are hidden by default.

I want to show and hide tables based on the selected option value.  Show the table with matching ID to selected option value, and hide the others not matching.

The code below works for showing the matching table.  But how do I hide a table if not matching the selected option?

```
$('#unit_table').hide();

$('#program_levels').change(function(){
            if($("#" + this.value + "_table").is(":hidden")){
                $("#" + this.value + "_table").show();
            } else {

            }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of ends with attribute selector to hide all non matching tables having id ends with `_table`, see below code

[**JQuery Ends with Attribute Selector API**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('#unit_table').hide();

$('#program_levels').change(function(){
    //hide all tables 
    $("table[id$='_table'").hide();
    //show all matching tables only
    //if($("#" + this.value + "_table").is(":hidden")){ // if condition not required
         $("#" + this.value + "_table").show();
    //} 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".jsTable tr").hide();
   $(".jsSelect").change(function(){
     var oVal = $(this).val();
      $(".jsTable tr").hide();
     if(oVal!="")
     {
      $(".jsTable tr[id="+oVal+"]").show();
     }
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

<h2>Show hide</h2>
<select class="jsSelect">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<br/>
<table class="jsTable"> 
  <tr id="A">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
 <tr id="B">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
 <tr id="C">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="D">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#someid").attr("sometable") === "something") {
                // code
}
```